# Count NULLs in a pivot

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the below query but my query does not count `NULLs` How can I capture the count of Nulls?

```
SELECT
*
FROM (
  SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(T.END_DATE,'YYYYMM') AS MNTH_END,
  CD, CD AS CD2
  FROM T 
                               )
PIVOT
(
COUNT(CD2) 
FOR MNTH_END IN  (201801, 201802,201803,201804,201805,201806,201807,201808,201809,201810,201811,201812,201901)
)
ORDER BY CD
```

Data:

```
CD    201801 201802 201803 201804 
  A       25    26      27     28
  B      101    102    103    104
  null    0      0      0      0
```

Comment: Including the raw data from `T` would be helpful - or at least a sample, with the current and expected results for that sample. From the 'data' you've shown, which seems to be the result, you have no rows with null `CD` values anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `count()` function never counts nulls, so the problem is the `COUNT(CD)` - if `CD` is null then the count will be zero, as you're seeing.

You can count the `MNTH_END` value instead, and if you do that you don't need the extra copy of `CD`:

```
SELECT
*
FROM (
  SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(T.END_DATE, 'YYYYMM') AS MNTH_END,
  CD
  FROM T 
)
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(MNTH_END) 
  FOR MNTH_END IN  ('201801', '201802', '201803', '201804')
)
ORDER BY CD;
```

Demo with sample data (including made-up null counts) in a CTE, and with th epivot values trimmed for brevity:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with t (cd, end_date) as (
            select 'A', date '2018-01-01' from dual connect by level <= 25
  union all select 'B', date '2018-01-01' from dual connect by level <= 101
  union all select null, date '2018-01-01' from dual connect by level <= 11
  union all select 'A', date '2018-02-01' from dual connect by level <= 26
  union all select 'B', date '2018-02-01' from dual connect by level <= 102
  union all select null, date '2018-02-01' from dual connect by level <= 12
  union all select 'A', date '2018-03-01' from dual connect by level <= 27
  union all select 'B', date '2018-03-01' from dual connect by level <= 103
  union all select null, date '2018-03-01' from dual connect by level <= 13
  union all select 'A', date '2018-04-01' from dual connect by level <= 28
  union all select 'B', date '2018-04-01' from dual connect by level <= 104
  union all select null, date '2018-04-01' from dual connect by level <= 14
)
-- actual query
SELECT
*
FROM (
  SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(T.END_DATE, 'YYYYMM') AS MNTH_END,
  CD
  FROM T 
)
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(MNTH_END) 
  FOR MNTH_END IN  ('201801', '201802', '201803', '201804')
)
ORDER BY CD;
```

```
C   '201801'   '201802'   '201803'   '201804'
- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A         25         26         27         28
B        101        102        103        104
          11         12         13         14
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something :

```
SELECT CD, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(T.END_DATE,'YYYYMM') = '201801' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "201801", 
       . . . 
       SUM(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(T.END_DATE,'YYYYMM') = '201901' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "201901" 
FROM T 
GROUP BY CD
ORDER BY CD;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `NVL` function

```
COUNT(NVL(CD2, 1))
```